# Many to many query per character not loading- how do I get it to display/edit/add?

Tags: php, mysql

I have several tables.

pcharacters
(id, name, and plenty of other columns)

skill
(skid,description,cost)

playerskill
(playerid,skillid,rank)

the player and skill id are inner joined with their respective cohort.

I am having a hard time having the skills displayed for a created character. So a person can create a character and with up to 10 skills. My current query will not populate and I"m having a hard time seeing if it makes sense. so my question is how can I display not my skillid but the name and rank (there are 10 ranks) for skill id.

```
$queryskill = "SELECT * FROM skills
INNER JOIN playerskill
ON skills.skid = playerskill.skillid where charid = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want -

```
$queryskill = "SELECT * FROM skills
INNER JOIN playerskill
ON skills.skid = playerskill.skillid where playerid = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."'";
                                           ^^^^^^^^
```

Take a look at this SQLFiddle example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d10c/5